# Grails project on Jboss 7 Blocks logging

Tags: grails, logging, jboss7.x

I have a grails project that I am attempting to get working correctly for my company.   We had the project running smoothly on Jboss 4.2.3, but upgrading to Jboss 7 causes a problem. When I deploy the grails war with another ear project in the deployments folder of jboss 7,  Jboss stops logging part way through the deploy. 
Both the grails war and the ear project deploy properly, but logging just doesn't work.
Also even after deploy, when I run a webservice that is available from the ear project, the webservice method runs properly, but the logging I added to the webservice method doesn't show up in the logs.  If I stop the server and remove the grails project and restart it and run the same webservice method all of the logging shows up, also all of the logging that was supposed to show up during deployment.

I'm not seeing any errors in the logs involving class loader issues. 
Please someone throw me a bone!

Sincerely,

David

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to edit the Jboss configuration, which is usually an xml file.

See [JBoss AS7 Logging](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7Logging)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be overriding logging. Do you have some code that is removing log handlers or anything like that? There some [logging documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration) though I suspect that's not the issue. It really seems like something is probably clearing log handlers.